# In search of a word: Contingent but without fail

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, american-english

I'm in search of a certain word which I cannot find in the dictionary or the internet, but I found something like it.

The word is contingent.

> con·tin·gent  (kn-tnjnt)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Liable to occur but not with certainty; possible: "All salaries are reckoned on contingent as well as on actual services" (Ralph Waldo Emerson).
> 2. Dependent on conditions or occurrences not yet established; conditional: arms sales contingent on the approval of Congress. See Synonyms at dependent.
> 3. Happening by chance or accident; fortuitous. See Synonyms at accidental.
> 4. Logic True only under certain conditions; not necessarily or universally true: a contingent proposition.
>
> (From http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contingent)

The difference from this word and the word I am looking for would be that the meaning/definition of the word would go as follows:

> adj.
>
> 1. Only under certain conditions or circumstances but without fail, it will always succeed.
> 2. Is not accidental, nor by any means of luck but is conditional.
> 3. Does not require chance, To occur without fail, but only if certain conditions are met.

To expand on 3 a bit more, what I mean by "Does not require chance" would be that it's going or not going to happen; that if luck were to play in it that the outcome would still be the same no matter how lucky you were.

Comment: I don't think your question is clear, but are you thinking of 'inevitable'? Or 'consequential', 'resulting', 'ensuing'? The expression 'inevitable consequence/s' seems to come closest to what you are asking for.

Comment: In a way I am, but that is only a small part of the word I am looking for. The other part would have to be that like I said before, certain condition must be met before success.

Comment: @BlazeOfLight Perhaps you have answered your own question there - doesn't 'conditional' fit the criteria? e.g. "The success of the project was conditional on securing the funding."

Comment: @Alo In logic terminology, C is a necessary and sufficient condition for O.

Comment: Are you looking for "*X is **predicated** upon Y*"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the word ***contingent:***

> 2. (**contingent on/upon**) Occurring or existing only if (certain circumstances) are the case; dependent on:
>      *his fees were contingent on the success of his search*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingent)

Note that you need to use the preposition *on/upon* with *contingent* in this sense. But it does mean that the result is guaranteed if and only if certain conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for your help. I was just looking for a single word in particular. This should work nicely.

Comment: I'm confused. OP said that 'contingent' was a word in the same ballpark.

Comment: I think *contingent* is in the same ballpark as *contingent upon*.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the phrase you want is **"a consequence"**.

If A happens, then B **must** occur then B is a consequence of A.